# Question about looping after a scene is activated in Home Assistant

Tags: node-red

So what I am trying to do is to use a loop node to activate a switch multiple times based on a scene getting activated in Home assistant. Any advice would be helpful. I've added the JSON for reference.

```
[
    {
        "id": "023b12ef7d84d6be",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Flow 1",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": "",
        "env": []
    },
    {
        "id": "789192c486d850ff",
        "type": "trigger-state",
        "z": "023b12ef7d84d6be",
        "name": "",
        "server": "58789d9e.7d1274",
        "version": 4,
        "inputs": 0,
        "outputs": 2,
        "exposeAsEntityConfig": "",
        "entityId": "scene.bed_time",
        "entityIdType": "exact",
        "debugEnabled": true,
        "constraints": [
            {
                "targetType": "this_entity",
                "targetValue": "",
                "propertyType": "current_state",
                "propertyValue": "new_state.state",
                "comparatorType": "is",
                "comparatorValueDatatype": "str",
                "comparatorValue": ""
            }
        ],
        "customOutputs": [],
        "outputInitially": true,
        "stateType": "habool",
        "enableInput": false,
        "x": 360,
        "y": 420,
        "wires": [
            [
                "352070a3682a3c6e"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "352070a3682a3c6e",
        "type": "loop",
        "z": "023b12ef7d84d6be",
        "name": "",
        "kind": "fcnt",
        "count": "2",
        "initial": "1",
        "step": "1",
        "condition": "",
        "conditionType": "js",
        "when": "before",
        "enumeration": "enum",
        "enumerationType": "msg",
        "limit": "200",
        "loopPayload": "loop-index",
        "finalPayload": "final-count",
        "x": 670,
        "y": 420,
        "wires": [
            [],
            [
                "5be6c2b4b2e0d7c3"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5be6c2b4b2e0d7c3",
        "type": "trigger-state",
        "z": "023b12ef7d84d6be",
        "name": "",
        "server": "58789d9e.7d1274",
        "version": 4,
        "inputs": 1,
        "outputs": 2,
        "exposeAsEntityConfig": "",
        "entityId": "switch.bot_5320",
        "entityIdType": "exact",
        "debugEnabled": true,
        "constraints": [
            {
                "targetType": "this_entity",
                "targetValue": "",
                "propertyType": "current_state",
                "propertyValue": "new_state.state",
                "comparatorType": "is",
                "comparatorValueDatatype": "str",
                "comparatorValue": "turn on"
            }
        ],
        "customOutputs": [],
        "outputInitially": false,
        "stateType": "str",
        "enableInput": true,
        "x": 680,
        "y": 620,
        "wires": [
            [
                "352070a3682a3c6e",
                "c0a20b484f79bf66"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "c0a20b484f79bf66",
        "type": "debug",
        "z": "023b12ef7d84d6be",
        "name": "debug 1",
        "active": true,
        "tosidebar": true,
        "console": true,
        "tostatus": true,
        "complete": "payload",
        "targetType": "msg",
        "statusVal": "payload",
        "statusType": "auto",
        "x": 1020,
        "y": 680,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "58789d9e.7d1274",
        "type": "server",
        "name": "Home Assistant",
        "addon": true
    }
]
```

I've tried using the debug note and it seems the State of the scene is a time stamp form what I can tell which seems a bit strange.